# vSphere client перестал коннектиться к ESXi 5.5

Tags: vmware, hyper-v

vSphere client перестал коннектиться к ESXi 5.5. Текст ошибки:

```
Call "ServiceInstance.RetrieveContent" for object "ServiceInstance" on Server failed.

The request failed because the remote server took too long to respond. (The command has timed out as the remote server is taking too long to respond)
```

В тот день когда клиент перестал коннектиться на гипервизоре ничего не настраивал. Пробовал коннектиться с разных компьютеров, сначала появляется сообщение о недоверенном сертификате, потом клиент долго пытается коннектиться, после чего везде возникает одна и та же ошибка.

Сервер с гипервизором пингуется. Делал telnet <адрес сервера> 443. Результат - черное окно командной строки.

Все виртуальные машины работают, пингуются и доступны по портам ssh, 443, 80, rdp.

Скан портов нмапом:

```
Not shown: 989 filtered ports

PORT     STATE  SERVICE

22/tcp   closed ssh

80/tcp   open   http

427/tcp  open   svrloc

443/tcp  open   https

902/tcp  open   iss-realsecure

5988/tcp closed wbem-http

5989/tcp open   wbem-https

8000/tcp open   http-alt

8080/tcp closed http-proxy

8100/tcp open   xprint-server

8300/tcp closed tmi
```

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ дан на сайте vmware:

[vSphere Client times out before authentication to ESXi completes (2072539)](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=2072539)